# Jackson Mixin for Class having a List of same Class

Tags: java, json, jackson, mixins, pojo

I have a class

```
public class Rectangle
{
  int a;
  int b;
  List<Rectangle> c;
}
```

I want to use Jackson mixin for this class to modify the Rectangle class using Jackson annotations. Will using below code for List will work?

```
 @JsonProperty("c")
 abstract List<Rectangle> getC();
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: > Will using below code for List will work?
Have you tried it ?

Comment: This is only a sample code. My actual code is very complex and I didn't want to make any changes without complete knowledge of whether it'll work or not.
Please help if you have ever tried this. I couldn't find any helpful link regarding this.

Comment: what prevents you from trying this simple code, on your own machine ?

Comment: `Don't ask about... Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)` [http://stackoverflow.com/tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @dream_world: Try it out in a unit-test to avoid contaminating your actual code.

Comment: I tried the above code and it worked perfectly fine. Thanks for the suggestion @Henrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the suggestion by @Henrik and @zeppelin. I tried out the code and it works fine having a List of same class objects when using Jackson mixin.